# Text selection and magnifier implementation for a customized UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Kindle app does their own, currently what's the best third party implementation out there? I am not asking for how to implement, but who have done the best.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Core Text (what I think kindle must use) with text selection, loupe/magnifier view and all the other perks `UITextView` has, you should check out OmniGroups's OmniUI framework on [GitHub](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad).

Take a look at the TextEditor example, it shows an editable Core Text view with text selection and everything else `UITextView` has, aswell as the ability to add styles to individual ranges of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this example for a nice magnifying glass: http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/03/a-simpler-magnifying-glass-loupe-view-for-the-iphone